# nokogiri: why is this an invalid xpath?

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

```
//br/preceding-sibling::normalize-space(text())
```

i am getting invalid xpath expression with nokogiri

Answer (score 10, accepted):

normalize-space is a function.  You can't use it there.
You need a node-set.

maybe you mean

```
//br/preceding-sibling::*
```

or you could use normalize-space in a *predicate*, inside square brackets. Think of the predicate as a filter or selector on the node-set.  So you can do this:

```
//br/preceding-sibling::*[normalize-space()='Fred']
```

In English that translates to  "all elements preceding `<br>` in the document, and for which the (normalized) text is 'Fred' ".  In this document:

```
<html>
  <p>
    <h2>Fred</h2>
    <br/>
  </p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

...the xpath expression selects the `<h2>` node.

I figured this out with the [free XpathVisualizer tool available on codeplex](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com).

[image]