# How do I cut phrases off a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, nokogiri

I wasn't sure about my questions name. I have an HTML page I got using nokogiri. Now I want to cut some tags off that page. I tried using ruby's delete method after converting the html to a string - Though it deletes all the letters I entered. The best result i got was using `.gsub('<stuff>', '')` though it still leaves some space. Is it possible to actually cut stuff of a string? specific pharses?
Another question - Can I remove spaces?

what I done so far :

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.example.com/"))
tester = doc.css(".example").to_s.gsub('<div class="example">', '')
```

Comment: Meant phrase. Sorry, spelling mistake.

Comment: Could you give some simple real input and output data, that would explain what things you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please do what Dogbert says if you want help. Your question is not yet clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest trying to do it at the xml tree level rather than string editing.
I think the nokogiri api gives you some tools for doing this.

Another approach might be selecting the data you want, with css or xpath, rather than deleting the parts you don't want?

There's also an xpath function for normalising space in strings, there's an example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551192/nokogiri-why-is-this-an-invalid-xpath)

Some nokogiri help:

- [Intro article on Engineyard](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/getting-started-with-nokogiri/)
- [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri)/[Asciicasts](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri)
- [Official tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials)

Comment: How do I do it in an xml tree level? I would really like to understand that, and I didn't really get the nokigiri's xml api...

Comment: It gives you back a node set, which you then navigate like a tree. I added some tutorial links to the answer. The API can be tricky, but spend some time playing with it (in IRB) and you'll find it very useful if you work with HTML or XML parsing in Ruby again (and many other libraries use it behind-the-scenes).

Comment: +1 for working with XML tree.  If you start doing Regexs in XML/HTML you get into a lot of trouble.  Nokogiri is very important to know and it is nearly the same in any language to traverse/replace tags.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Nokogiri's Tutorials. In particular, you want to read ["Modifying an HTML / XML Document", Changing text contents](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html).

Nokogiri's XML accessors are very friendly, because you don't need to use XPath. You can use CSS accessors also, and for people who aren't in XML all day long they can help a lot.

In that particular example, they're using the `at_css` method, which searches for the first occurrence of the target. You have many alternate methods, which are synonyms: `at`, `%`, `at_css` and `at_xpath` handle "find the first one" cases. `search`, `css`, `xpath`, `/` similarly handle "find all occurrences".

For instance:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<h1>Snap, Crackle and Pop</h1>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
h1 = doc.at('h1') 
h1.content = h1.content[0, h1.content.length - 3] + '...'

puts doc.to_html

>> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
>> <html><body><h1>Snap, Crackle and ...</h1></body></html>
```

That creates a new HTML document in Nokogiri, searches for the first H1, and trims the trailing three characters in its contents, replacing them with an ellipsis.